# Key and field in redis?

Tags: redis

Here is the Redis doc says about Hash `HSET` command

```
    Redis HSET command is used to set field in the hash stored at the key to value.
```

Command

```
  HSET KEY_NAME FIELD VALUE
```

Example

```
    HSET user:A:address  city NY
```

I believe `user:A:address` is the hashmap name , city is the key and NY is the value. Right ?

Actually above doc(`HSET KEY_NAME FIELD VALUE`) mentions hashmap name as key and key as field. So bit confused

Comment: Yes, you got the right idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`user:A:address` is the key name (KEY_NAME) in the Redis keyspace, which in your example is of type Hash. `city` is the field name inside that Hash, and `NY` is that field's value.

Using the doc and replacing the terms with your example's values:

> Redis HSET command is used to set `city` in the hash stored at `user:A:address` to `NY`.

Comment: Can we say `user:A:address` is the name of hashmap ? When i do `HSET user:A:attribute age 10` then `user:A:attribute ` will be different hashmap than  `user:A:address` Right ?

Answer (score 2):

Redis Hash is generally used to store fields and values related to a key. We can store multiple keys in Redis hash.

For example : Lets consider we want to store the username , email_id , contact_no and other fields of a user. We can use userId as key in Redis hash and username, emailid , contact_no as fields and their corresponding values as values.

```
Key : userId (1234)
Field : username  Value : test
Field : emailid Value : test@123.com
Field : contact_no Value : 1234567890
```

Similarly we can store required fields for all users using a unique key ( userID in this example)